# I installed the Python module, but it still says it's not there's no module

Tags: python

When I make Python code, I keep getting errors.
(No module named 'sklearn' and Failed to open file

```
b'C:\\Users\\\xea\xb9\x80\xec\x8a\xb9\xec\xb2\xa0\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scipy-zgoub8mi'
  File "C:\python\Bode_plot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scipy import signal
```

-->The two errors are different codes)

Can I get some help?
I've already tried all the ways on the GOOGLE :(
PLEASE HELP ME..

module error:
[image: MODULE ERROR]

os error:
[image: OS ERROR?]

Comment: `sklearn --version` in cmd if this gives the version of the module then comment.

Comment: Have you checked your PATH variables in system and ide?

Comment: avm) Sorry :( I don't know because I'm a newbie developer.. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: sharim lqbal) When I typed "sklearn --version" in cmd, it dosen't work.. It comes out like this. ('sklearn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.)

Comment: Looks like scikit-learn is not installed on your system. Refer [here](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/install.html)

Comment: But i already install scikit-learn on cmd at before 3 hours... When I try to install it, It prints out Requirement already satisfied.

Comment: Then you might have installed scikit in different environment but using other environment in your ide...post screenshot of complete screen